# post method not working in yii2 active form

Tags: php, yii, yii2, active-form

I have created active form in my yii2 application with following code

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'deposit-form',
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'template' => '{input}{error}',
        'options' => [
            'tag' => false
        ]
    ],
    'action' => 'create',
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'form-horizontal',
        'method' => 'post',
    ]
])
```

however my form is not displaying any mthod i.e, get or post.
output of my form is

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
```

I wan't it as `<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">`

How to achieve following result
I also tried this code

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'deposit-form',
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'template' => '{input}{error}',
        'options' => [
            'tag' => false
        ]
    ],
    'action' => 'create',
    'method' => 'post',
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'form-horizontal',

    ]
])
```

Comment: add method='post' in your form and check, refer below ans for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In the [official documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#$method-detail):

$method public property:
The form submission method. This should be either 'post' or 'get'. Defaults to 'post'.

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'method' => 'get',
    'action' => ['controller/action'],
]);
```

Comment: I used method='post', you could see it in my code but it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Use Following, you can add other properties also. Your code is also correct, but  I think you are not ending your form.

```
<?php   $form = \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::begin([
                'id' => 'deposit-form',
                'enableClientValidation' => true,
                'method'=>'post'
            ]);
            \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::end();
```

?>